# document.cookie returns undefined 1 in 13 times

Tags: javascript, cookies, undefined

Im sorry if this question sounds one previously asked. However after looking through the other answers, my exact problem was not addressed. 
My code generates many cookies successfully but in only one occurrence document.cookie returns an empty string. I only recieve an error message on a function that calls the wrongly undefined cookie. In the variable details list from the debugger, i found "<return>: undefined;" appears immediately before the bad cookie is returned.

This works:

```
function selectChall() {
    var challengeArray = JSON.parse(CookieUtil.get("challenge"));
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
    if (challengeArray[rand] == null || challengeArray[rand] == "undefined") {
        selectChall();
    } else {
        document.cookie = ("challNum="+ encodeURIComponent(rand));
    }
}
```

### //Selects random array value if that value is defined. Value is made into cookie. Used to choose next html page

This does not work:

```
function selectItem() {
    var itemArray = JSON.parse(CookieUtil.get("items"));
    var itm1 = CookieUtil.get("item1");
    var itm2 = CookieUtil.get("item2");
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    if (rand == 0 || itemArray[rand] == "") {
        rand="";
        selectItem();
    } else {
        SetNewItem(itemArray[rand]);
    }
}
function SetNewItem(itm){
    var itm1 = CookieUtil.get("item1");
    var itm2 = CookieUtil.get("item2");
    if (itm1 == "") {
        document.cookie = ("item1="+ encodeURIComponent(itm));
    } else {
        document.cookie = ("item2="+ encodeURIComponent(itm)); 
    }
}
//Selects random array value if that value is defined and is not first value in array. Then converts the value into cookie to be called on another page
```

Tried in Chrome(on a server) and Firefox(locally).

Checking the cookie list confirms that out of 13 cookies, item2 is the only one without a value

When i call the cookie, (rate(challNum, itm2)).toString() breaks
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined"

```
function StartChallenge(challNum) {
    var itemchoice;
    var itm1 = CookieUtil.get("item1");
    var itm2 = CookieUtil.get("item2");
    var itemArray = JSON.parse(CookieUtil.get("items"));

    //document.write((CookieUtil.get("Name")) +", " + "Choose an Item:");

         var LI1 = document.getElementById("PlaceItem1");
        var button1 = document.createElement("button");
        button1.setAttribute("onClick", "choice('item1')");//onclick
        var Btn1Text = document.createTextNode(CookieUtil.get("item1"));//name of item
        var SuccessMsg1 = document.createTextNode(" (Success Rate: " + ((rate(challNum, CookieUtil.get("item1"))).toString())+"%)");//rate
        button1.appendChild(Btn1Text);
        LI1.appendChild(button1);
        LI1.appendChild(SuccessMsg1);

         var LI2 = document.getElementById("PlaceItem2");
        var button2 = document.createElement("button");
        button2.setAttribute("onClick", "choice(item2)");
        var Btn2Text = document.createTextNode(CookieUtil.get("item2"));

        **var RateString2=(rate(challNum, itm2)).toString();**

        var SuccessMsg2 = document.createTextNode(" (Success Rate: " +RateString2+"%)");
        button2.appendChild(Btn2Text);
        LI2.appendChild(button2);
        LI2.appendChild(SuccessMsg2);

    function choice(itm) {
        itemchoice = itm;
    }
    Playlist(challNum, itemchoice);
}
```

Comment: What is that code trying to do? Without a clear explanation of what you want the behavior to be, it's hard to help.

Comment: item2 should be defined as a cookie and then called in another function.  Both functions including "Rate" do work when "item" is given a value manually(made into a cookie) outside of a function.